# Why is the fill behind text in filled excel cells different than the rest of the filled cells?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

For some reason, this problem started in all of my spreadsheets yesterday, so I must have clicked something, but I do not know what it could be.  Here is the problem: I have a filled cell. I type words in the filled cell.  The color behind the text changes to a different color, making it look as if the text is hightlighted.  How do I stop that from happening?  I am using Excel 2010.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a few cells, and then going to the fill button in the ribbon and choosing "No Fill", if that puts those cells back to "normal" then you can select the rest of the affected cells and do the same.

You can also select an affected cell, click Home -- Cell Styles (in the Styles section of the ribbon).  See if the cell has a style applied to it.  If so, choose Normal (usually the top left choice in the selection pane).  If that corrects the problem, then select all the affected cells and do the same to set them to Normal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried both of your suggestions, but it doesn't make any change.  The cell style was normal and when I change the fill or remove the fill and a new one, it just changes back to the "highlighted" fill.  Oddly enough, it is also changing the fill color behind the text in the formatting box (where you change the font style, etc.).  And it is happening in all of the spreadsheets I am opening, so I feel it must be a setting for the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue wasn't with excel but with my entire computer (PC).  There was an update waiting but it didn't want to process all the way through.  The IT person at work helped me get the update to complete (took over an hour to wait for everything to complete).  So my suggestion would be to restart/update and see if that helps.  (BTW, I usually only restart on the weekends, so it was a new update, and I didn't have any message that it was waiting.) Thanks again for your suggestions!